# How is constant lookup resolved when two files mutually depend on each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constants

I have models `A` and `B`, and two versions of constants `Foo` and `Bar` name-spaced in each model:

app/models/a.rb

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  FOO = "foo in A"
  BAR = B::FOO
end
```

app/models/b.rb

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  FOO = "foo in B"
  BAR = A::FOO
end
```

Here, `A::BAR` is dependent on `B::FOO`, which is defined in file `b.rb`, which has the definition of `B::BAR`, which is dependent on `A::FOO`, which is defined in file `a.rb`, which has the definition of `A::BAR`. Yet, I can call `A::BAR` without an error:

```
A::BAR # => "foo in B"
```

To me, this looks cyclic, and I cannot imagine any order or way in which the two files are loaded without falling into infinite recursion.

How is constant lookup resolved when I call `A::BAR`?

---

I also found out that if I call `B::BAR` at the very beginning before calling `A::BAR`, then it raises an error, which suggests that the alphabetical order of the file names `a.rb` and `b.rb` is related to this issue. This also raises a question: if file loading is triggered by constant resolution, then such order between the files should not matter. On the other hand, if files are loaded before these constants are called, then whether to call `A::BAR` first or `B::BAR` first should not matter. What is going on here?

---

I also found that if I change the order of definitions to the following,

app/models/a.rb

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  BAR = B::FOO
  FOO = "foo in A"
end
```

app/models/b.rb

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  BAR = A::FOO
  FOO = "foo in B"
end
```

then either calling `A::BAR` first or calling `B::BAR` first would raise an error. I wonder how this is related.